# Override the PlayStation 4 DualShock Controllers in Windows 10

Tags: ps4, controllers, windows-10, hardware

I'm using a PlayStation 4 DualShock controller on Windows 10. I want to change the controller behaviours for the operating system as a whole.

I want the "O" button to be "pressed" if it's y-axis measures more than 6m/s² via the controllers built-in accelerometer. I want that condition to be applied in every game I play, where the game still sees the button as "O".

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this + the edit, Gnem!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there are no tools to remap accelerometer thresholds to button presses at this point.

There is a tool for remapping a DS4 called [DS4Windows](https://github.com/Ryochan7/DS4Windows), but it doesn't allow you to remap the accelerometer. If you are really interested, you should probably make a feature request in the repository.